# Kinect v2 how to use relativetime to count gesture action time

Tags: c#, kinect

so basically I am using the vitruvius source code to create my gesture, however to make it more efficient i want to add a timer to count how long the gesture takes to call it successful, so my gesture needs 3 positions to call it swipeleft, I need to get the relativetime(timespan) of each position then add them up, if they are below a certain timing e.g. 2s then they are counted as a gesture, however i tried using relativetime and i get a result of 00:00:00:00/0s meaning my timespan have not started yet

Comment: Can you give the code for how you are using realtivetime?

Comment: Well the thing is relativetime is part of the Kinect library, but I do not know how to use it and there are no examples on how to use it